# A columnbreak command in the vwcol package?

Tags: multicol, columnbreak

I am using the package [vwcol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/vwcol) to create a two column document wherein the columns have different widths. I need a command like \columnbreak in package [multicol](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf). How can I do this? Thank you in advance!
Update- as John Kormylo suggested in the first comment, I tried \newpage or \pagebreak, which work, however, these command distort the justification in of the text that follows them. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{vwcol}

\begin{document}
\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.4, 0.6}, justify=flush]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent et maximus tellus. In rhoncus augue ac nibh ultricies feugiat. Nulla eu lacinia diam, et elementum quam. Aliquam consectetur facilisis aliquam. Duis ultrices id nibh a sagittis. Proin consequat est tortor, non tristique ex placerat in. Aenean tempor molestie dolor, et fringilla nisl ultrices sed. Nulla id neque tincidunt, tincidunt ante eget, dignissim ligula.
\newpage

In Blandit facilisis diam in ultricies. Donec vulputate nulla vel felis pulvinar vehicula. Nullam at nisl at felis vulputate pellentesque eu at risus. Nulla consectetur lorem in nulla rhoncus, fermentum consequat purus semper. Proin vehicula nisl vitae gravida tristique. In nec sapien finibus, dictum leo aliquet, dictum ipsum. Cras neque risus, porta sit amet arcu eu, tincidunt posuere orci. Duis dapibus ligula velit, eget ornare justo aliquam vitae.

Vivamus sed vehicula libero. Donec id felis vitae elit imperdiet porta at vestibulum eros. Suspendisse venenatis sollicitudin ligula, vitae aliquet felis blandit at. Aliquam efficitur lorem orci, eget convallis eros porttitor eget. In facilisis lectus non nisi viverra, nec gravida tellus euismod.
\end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```

The justification after \newpage or \pagebreak gets messed up when there is considerable amount of text and at least one paragraph. Commenting the newpage command in above example gives a sensible output.

Comment: I would try \newpage or \pagebreak. These normally break columns; multicol redefines them and uses \columnbreak instead.  The question is whether vwcol can handle gaps, since it pre-formats the entire page using \everypar and \parshape.

Comment: It seems that vwcol cannot handle gaps. \newpage or \pagebreak works, however, the justification distorts after the first paragraph that follows one of above command.

Comment: Pity!  It can be done recursively, but is much slower.